# Quando executo cUrl para localhost:8080 ele não consegue se comunicar

Tags: php, libcurl, docker

**Quando executo cUrl para localhost:8080 ele não consegue se comunicar**

```
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
```

O código acima pertence à: **localhost:8000**

Onde estou tentando me comunicar com: **localhost:8080**, pois ele da o seguinte erro:

**Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused**

Estou usando Docker para gerar meus contêineres (não sei se essa informação vai ajudar)

O que está acontecendo? Qual a solução para este problema?

Comment: Tem certeza de que está utilizando o servidor nesta porta, `8080`?  O padrão para aplicações web tende a ser `80` ou `443`, por exemplo. Experimente utilizar o `127.0.0.1` ao invés do `localhost`. Isso não parece ser um erro do CURL. Se estiver tentando se conectar com outro servidor externo veja também se está com a porta aberta, por exemplo no IPTables, mas não é esse o caso!

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, acho que foi falta de atenção pois o docker vc abre uma porta na sua máquina e uma no contêiner. Vou verificar melhor essa questão.

Comment: Oi, tente adicionar 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: Acho que descobri um possível problema. Por eu estar usando docker e fazendo o PHP se conectar com outra aplicação, por consequência o PHP está dentro do docker, certo. Porém como não linkei o contêiner que quero me comunicar, é como se ele não existisse. Pois estou acessando de dentro do contêiner, mas vou dar uma olhada melhor. Só pensei nisso por enquanto

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que você disse, você executa 2 contêineres distintos e necessita que um acesse o outro através da rede do docker. Vou tentar te ajudar nisso.

## Ambiente

- ConteinerA: pilha PHP
- ConteinerB: servidor WEB

Ação desejada: Contêiner A faz requisição em Contêiner B através de biblioteca cURL do PHP para acessar um conteúdo http.

## Solução

Como exemplo, tome os seguintes arquivos criados em uma mesma pasta vazia:

1) *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:
  conteinerA:
    image: php:cli
    command: php /app/script.php
    volumes:
     - ./script.php:/app/script.php
    networks:
      - default

  conteinerB:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./index.html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
    networks:
      - default
```

2) *script.php* (rodará no conteinerA)

```
<?php
sleep(10); #aguardar o outro conteiner iniciar
$url = "http://conteinerB/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $res;
?>
```

3) *index.html* (será o recurso disponibilizado pelo conteinerB)

```
Informacao vinda do ConteinerB
```

Navegue até a pasta onde estão os 3 arquivos e execute o comando:

```
docker-compose up
```

No final da saída do terminal você verá algo como:

```
conteinerA_1  | Informacao vinda do ConteinerB
conteinerB_1  | 192.168.16.3 - - [30/Jan/2018:19:23:40 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 33
```

Isso significa que o conteinerA conseguiu acessar o conteinerB.

## Explicação

O *docker-compose* é um comando do docker que descreve serviços multi-contêineres e depois facilita sua orquestração e gerenciamento.

No arquivo *docker-compose.yml* estamos declarando os 2 serviços como você solicitou. Estes serviços serão executados usando as imagens **php:cli** e **httpd** que são distribuidas através do registro público do Docker *http://hub.docker.com*. Elas foram configuradas para poderem rodar scripts PHP na **php:cli** e para servir arquivos através do protocolo HTTP utilizando o apache2 na **httpd**. Quando a imagem httpd foi criada, foi configurado para servir os arquivos de */usr/local/apache2/htdocs* através da porta 80.

Incluimos os outros 2 arquivos em seus respectivos contêineres através da cláusula volumes: No conteinerA aparecerá montado na pasta */app* o arquivo *script.php*, enquanto que no conteinerB o arquivo *index.html* aparecerá na pasta */usr/local/apache2/htdocs* que é a padrão do apache2 nesta imagem.

Também definimos que os dois contêineres estarão em uma mesma rede *default* e definimos o comando inicial do containerA como *php /app/script.php*. Desta forma o script será executado e a saída será exposta na saída padrão do contêiner.

Além disso, no *docker-compose.yml* expomos o conteinerB para o computador hospedeiro. Conectamos a porta 80 do conteinerB para a porta 8080 do hospedeiro para que você possa certificar que o apache está ok. Para isso é só acessar através do seu browser o caminho localhost:8080. Os dados serão redirecionados para conteinerB:80. **Mesmo se não fosse feita essa exposição de portas, o acesso direto do conteinerA ao conteinerB pelo PHP continuaria a funcionar, pois os dois contêineres já tem uma rede para eles e não dependem do hospedeiro para nada!**

### Vamos a mágica

Ao executar o comando *docker compose up* o docker cria uma rede para os contêineres, atribui acesso de rede com IPs específicos aos contêineres (o que pode ser constatado pelo log do apache que apresenta o ip 192.168.16.3 tentando acessá-lo) e executa cada um deles separadamente. Isso significa que depois de alguns segundos o conteinerB começa a servir o arquivo index.html pela porta 80, e no conteiner A, o script é executado até obter os dados do conteinerB através da biblioteca cURL do PHP.